# Wrong coloring of commands after comment line in ST2

Tags: syntax, sublimetext2

Syntax coloring is very useful, but I have problems with it in Sublime Text 2. In particular, when a line beginning with a command (like **ALLOCATE** in Fortran) is after one or more commented line, the command changes the color as if it is a variable.

```
ALLOCATE(XYZ%CC(3,NC(1),NC(2),NC(3)))
!ALLOCATE(XYZ%CV(3,NF(1),NF(2),NF(3)))
ALLOCATE(XYZ%CV(3,NC(1)+1,NC(2)+1,NC(3)+1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a bug. Report this as an issue to the author of the syntax highlighting file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question, but a bug report.

Comment: Ok. I thought there was a solution. Should I delete this "question"?

Comment: Can you suggest me the most effective way of reporting such a issue?
It's worth to mention that the problem is not related to the specific color scheme used.

Comment: What plugin you are using for Fortran syntax highlighting? or is it just stock Sublime Text?

Comment: This is a valid question. It is not off topic, and while it may be a bug - it clearly relates to tools used to do programming, and it is possible that someone has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be corrected by replacing `Packages/Fortran/Syntaxes/Fortran - Modern.tmLanguage` with [this version](https://gist.github.com/MattDMo/d650ac9ea2060aa4eac3). To use, save the raw version of the file in the gist as `Fortran - Modern.tmLanguage`. Next, in Sublime, select **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`** to open the `Packages` folder in your operating system's file manager. Open the `Fortran/Syntaxes` folder and replace the existing `Fortran - Modern.tmLanguage` file with the new one. Also, make sure you delete `Fortran - Modern.tmLanguage.cache`, otherwise the changes won't take effect.

Then end result is now:

[image: final]

in contrast with the original behavior:

[image: original]

---

### Why the change was needed, and how it works

I used [`PackageDev`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev) to translate the XML-based `.tmLanguage` file into a much more readable YAML-based format. In it, there were two sections defining comments, one for comment blocks starting with `!-`:

```yaml
- begin: (^[ \t]+)?(?=!-)
  beginCaptures:
    '1': {name: punctuation.whitespace.comment.leading.ruby}
  end: (?!\G)
  patterns:
  - name: comment.line.exclamation.mark.fortran.modern
    begin: '!-'
    beginCaptures:
      '0': {name: punctuation.definition.comment.fortran}
    end: \n
    patterns:
    - match: \\\s*\n
```

and one for comments just beginning with `!`:

```yaml
- begin: (^[ \t]+)?(?=!)
  beginCaptures:
    '1': {name: punctuation.whitespace.comment.leading.ruby}
  end: (?!\G)
  patterns:
  - name: comment.line.exclamation.fortran.modern
    begin: '!'
    beginCaptures:
      '0': {name: punctuation.definition.comment.fortran}
    end: \n
    patterns:
    - match: \\\s*\n
```

This additional complexity is unnecessary and confusing, and not even the right way of doing it. There is no need for a `punctuation.whitespace.comment.leading` scope (and where did that `.ruby` suffix come from?), and the regexes for the actual comment block were overly complex and incorrect.

I removed both of the above sections and replaced them with this simple section:

```yaml
- name: comment.line.exclamation.fortran.modern
  match: (!-?).*$\n?
  captures:
    '1': {name: punctuation.definition.comment.fortran}
```

The regex is quite straightforward: capture the first group in parentheses - a `!` optionally followed by a `-`, and scope it as the comment symbol. Then, match anything up to the end of the line (`$`), optionally terminated by a newline character. I'm not even completely sure of how the previous regexes worked...

Comment: That's so bad that I cannot accept such a complete answer twice! Thank you so much!